# A table with 80% text data type and 140 columns taking much time in table scan which slow down the query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with 100 columns where 80% column is `nvarchar(max)` and there is no way to change this data type cause i am getting this data from MySQL `text` type column. This table contains almost 30lacs records, so when I am selecting all the columns it takes too much time to show recordset. In this circumstance, i was interested to change this table as `column store` table but column store does not support `nvarchar(max)` data type and now **i am finding the way how I can design this table which will help to make query fast.**

Note I have tried with non clustered indexing by different column which has also not impacted in makig query fast.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use two tables?  If your original table as a primary key, define a new table as:

```
create table t_text (
     original_id int primary key,
     value nvarchar(max),
     foreign key (id) references original_table(original_id)
);
```

You would then join in this table when you want to use the column.

For inserting or updating the table, you can define a view that includes the text value.  With a trigger on the view you can direct updates to the correct table.

What you really want is vertical partitioning -- the ability to store columns in separate partitions.  This is a method for implementing this manually.

Comment: I have not got significant improvement after doing vertical partitioning .. I split main table into three more tables got almost the same performance .. any other idea which may help

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin . . . I should have added -- you only get improvement if you are not selecting the column.  But SQL Server may store large values on secondary pages.  It has never been clear to me if those pages are read if the columns are not selected.